# Google Tracks convert kml to shape and preserve attributes

Tags: shapefile, gdal, kml, ogr2ogr

I've been attempting to convert a Google Tracks kmz file to an ESRI shapefile using the GDAL and libkml(http://www.gdal.org/drv_libkml.html) which I built on my Ubuntu 14.04 (64-bit) system. The kml is a line vector but when converting with GDAL I end up with point data and all attributes concatenated into one field 'Description'. I've read a ton of articles which suggest that this may be the case with kml as they often have non-standard schema, but I wondered if anyone has had any jy converting Google Tracks to shapefile or other GIS format.

Here's how I'm attempting:

1. Unarchive the kmz to a kml file
2. Use the command line ogr2ogr to convert kml to shapefile as follows: `ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" myfile.shp myfile.kml`

As I said the shapefile ends up as point vector layer with two points as opposed to a line vector showing the actual path that I walked and recorded using Google Tracks. If I try and load the kml file directly into QGIS I also get point data not a line (note: QGIS is built against an older version of GDAL without libkml support - I built another version of GDAL with libkml support to test this conversion).

Alternatively, if I try and convert the kml to csv the attributes are preserved but no coordinates.

I have also tried converting to a geojson using the link I found here: gpsies.com/convert.do from a previous stackexchange question ([How to convert KML with tracks to Shapefiles?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/61570/how-to-convert-kml-with-tracks-to-shapefiles)) and loading straight in QGIS as a geojson. This preserves the line vector (track) but again loses all attributes.

---

link to an example kmz file here :https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-TLTa7JtM_FSk9JY0wwdmkwcHc/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Can you share you kmz file of something similar that behaves in the same way?

Comment: sure, link to an example kmz now attached...thanks

Comment: I tried to read your file with GDAL 2.0-dev with both available GDAL drivers "KML" and "LIBKML". KML driver gives the same result that you got and LIBKML does not find any features. I would ask from gdal-dev mailing list what's wrong with the kmz/kml file.

Comment: hey, using GDAL 2.0 dev did the kml import as a point layer or a line?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the reason this isn't converting to line feature directly is because it's not a KML LineString (how standard line features are usually encoded in KML).  If you unzip the KMZ and look at the doc.kml file inside, you'll see that it contains a Folder with 28 PhotoOverlay features, one Point Placemark for the start of the trip, one Placemark containing the Track (animated line), and one Point Placemark for the end of the trip. So when you convert using GDAL, the only normal geometries it's finding are the two points.

Sounds like you found a via geojson and QGIS to convert the track to a Line, but you say that it lost the attributes.  What attributes are you looking to retain? The Track has time-stamps for each vertex, as well as attached speed data at each vertex. But when converting it to a Line there's no way to apply those times or speeds as attributes to each vertex. If you wanted to save those you would need to convert the track to a series of points instead of a line.

The only other "attributes" I see are all in a single HTML blob in the description tag for the Point at the end of the trip. You could manually parse those out into attributes if you wanted.

So, using some find/replace, regex and a bit of manual cleanup, below is a LineString version of your KML Track, with the Description contents broken out into ExtendedData name/value pairs. That should convert to a Line with associated attribute table. You can copy/paste it into Earth to see it, or save as KML to import/convert it.

If you have lots of these to do, you might want to look at [GPSBabel](https://www.gpsbabel.org), which is a nice tool with both a UI and Commandline interfaces for all sorts of format conversions, and looks like it's able to convert KML Tracks into LineStrings.

```
<Placemark>
  <name>
    <![CDATA[Tuliza Trip 1]]>
  </name>
  <ExtendedData>
    <Data name="Name">
      <value><![CDATA[Tuliza Trip 1]]></value>
    </Data>
    <Data name="Activity_type">
      <value><![CDATA[driving]]></value>
    </Data>
    <Data name="Description">
      <value><![CDATA[-]]></value>
    </Data>
    <Data name="Total_distance">
      <value><![CDATA[4.45 km (2.8 mi)]]></value>
    </Data>
    <Data name="Total_time">
      <value><![CDATA[46:00]]></value>
    </Data>
    <Data name="Moving_time">
      <value><![CDATA[46:00]]></value>
    </Data>
    <Data name="Average_speed">
      <value><![CDATA[5.80 km/h (3.6 mi/h)]]></value>
    </Data>
    <Data name="Average_moving_speed">
      <value><![CDATA[5.80 km/h (3.6 mi/h)]]></value>
    </Data>
    <Data name="Max_speed">
      <value><![CDATA[25.26 km/h (15.7 mi/h)]]></value>
    </Data>
    <Data name="Average_pace">
      <value><![CDATA[10:20 min/km (16:39 min/mi)]]></value>
    </Data>
    <Data name="Average_moving_pace">
      <value><![CDATA[10:20 min/km (16:39 min/mi)]]></value>
    </Data>
    <Data name="Fastest_pace">
      <value><![CDATA[2:22 min/km (3:49 min/mi)]]></value>
    </Data>
    <Data name="Max_elevation">
      <value><![CDATA[22 m (72 ft)]]></value>
    </Data>
    <Data name="Min_elevation">
      <value><![CDATA[1 m (4 ft)]]></value>
    </Data>
    <Data name="Elevation_gain">
      <value><![CDATA[37 m (123 ft)]]></value>
    </Data>
    <Data name="Max_grade">
      <value><![CDATA[5 %]]></value>
    </Data>
    <Data name="Min_grade">
      <value><![CDATA[-12 %]]></value>
    </Data>
    <Data name="Recorded">
      <value><![CDATA[10/18/2014 07:25]]></value>
    </Data>
  </ExtendedData>
  <LineString>
    <coordinates>
      39.69889,-3.989249
      39.698919,-3.989176
      39.698926,-3.989154
      39.698953,-3.989105
      39.698967,-3.989073
      39.698997,-3.989015
      39.699017,-3.988991
      39.699029,-3.988913
      39.699045,-3.988879
      39.699068,-3.988811
      39.699074,-3.988781
      39.699094,-3.988728
      39.699104,-3.988692
      39.699114,-3.988651
      39.699136,-3.988585
      39.699154,-3.988534
      39.699174,-3.988486
      39.699193,-3.988433
      39.699212,-3.988383
      39.699228,-3.988337
      39.69925,-3.988294
      39.699282,-3.98821
      39.699301,-3.988164
      39.699318,-3.988116
      39.699336,-3.988065
      39.699356,-3.988014
      39.699371,-3.987968
      39.699384,-3.987925
      39.699399,-3.987881
      39.699431,-3.987799
      39.699448,-3.987756
      39.699465,-3.987712
      39.699482,-3.98767
      39.699509,-3.987599
      39.699521,-3.987565
      39.699532,-3.987506
      39.69954,-3.987473
      39.699556,-3.987435
      39.699585,-3.98737
      39.699607,-3.98732
      39.699632,-3.987265
      39.699645,-3.987205
      39.69967,-3.987148
      39.69969,-3.987093
      39.699708,-3.987033
      39.699729,-3.986977
      39.699748,-3.986924
      39.699781,-3.986855
      39.699786,-3.986829
      39.699813,-3.986765
      39.699827,-3.986734
      39.699858,-3.986655
      39.699871,-3.986614
      39.699882,-3.986567
      39.699901,-3.986519
      39.699932,-3.986436
      39.699948,-3.986399
      39.699979,-3.986321
      39.699987,-3.98629
      39.700014,-3.986219
      39.700022,-3.986181
      39.700034,-3.986116
      39.700045,-3.986091
      39.700062,-3.986018
      39.700072,-3.985993
      39.700097,-3.985912
      39.700107,-3.98588
      39.700124,-3.98581
      39.700135,-3.985778
      39.700168,-3.985723
      39.700188,-3.985698
      39.700214,-3.985642
      39.70023,-3.985611
      39.700243,-3.98557
      39.700255,-3.985508
      39.700269,-3.985463
      39.700283,-3.985419
      39.700312,-3.985333
      39.700331,-3.985292
      39.700346,-3.985252
      39.700359,-3.985205
      39.700373,-3.985165
      39.700383,-3.985117
      39.700414,-3.985032
      39.700431,-3.984992
      39.700462,-3.984914
      39.700478,-3.984875
      39.700505,-3.984796
      39.700514,-3.984758
      39.700542,-3.984683
      39.700555,-3.984645
      39.700577,-3.984578
      39.700591,-3.984546
      39.700615,-3.984474
      39.700625,-3.984444
      39.700644,-3.98438
      39.700656,-3.984349
      39.700678,-3.984286
      39.700687,-3.984255
      39.700713,-3.984173
      39.700721,-3.98415
      39.700741,-3.984094
      39.700754,-3.984064
      39.700784,-3.983999
      39.7008,-3.98397
      39.70082,-3.983909
      39.700829,-3.983882
      39.700859,-3.983813
      39.700863,-3.983793
      39.700891,-3.983714
      39.700894,-3.983697
      39.700924,-3.983626
      39.700933,-3.983609
      39.700936,-3.983532
      39.700927,-3.983518
      39.700863,-3.983481
      39.700843,-3.983473
      39.700784,-3.983447
      39.700753,-3.983434
      39.700679,-3.983398
      39.700647,-3.98338
      39.700589,-3.983351
      39.700564,-3.983339
      39.70049,-3.98331
      39.700474,-3.983303
      39.700425,-3.983279
      39.700389,-3.983261
      39.700319,-3.983226
      39.700283,-3.98321
      39.700206,-3.983173
      39.70019,-3.983162
      39.700111,-3.983119
      39.700107,-3.983119
      39.700032,-3.983096
      39.700012,-3.983091
      39.699934,-3.983059
      39.699909,-3.983046
      39.699834,-3.983014
      39.699822,-3.983009
      39.699761,-3.982974
      39.699742,-3.982963
      39.699673,-3.982928
      39.699652,-3.982918
      39.69957,-3.982882
      39.699556,-3.982875
      39.699481,-3.982839
      39.699467,-3.982833
      39.699405,-3.982805
      39.699378,-3.982799
      39.699311,-3.98277
      39.699283,-3.982748
      39.699215,-3.982724
      39.699187,-3.982718
      39.699109,-3.982691
      39.699088,-3.982683
      39.69902,-3.982645
      39.698991,-3.98263
      39.698923,-3.982595
      39.69889,-3.982579
      39.698812,-3.982536
      39.698794,-3.982526
      39.698731,-3.982506
      39.698707,-3.982498
      39.69865,-3.98247
      39.698611,-3.982453
      39.698535,-3.982419
      39.698501,-3.982404
      39.69843,-3.982369
      39.698415,-3.982365
      39.698349,-3.982331
      39.698327,-3.982318
      39.698247,-3.982275
      39.698224,-3.982265
      39.698141,-3.982237
      39.698126,-3.982229
      39.698067,-3.982165
      39.698066,-3.982151
      39.698102,-3.982073
      39.698108,-3.982058
      39.698146,-3.981976
      39.698155,-3.98196
      39.698194,-3.981882
      39.698197,-3.981871
      39.698221,-3.981788
      39.698226,-3.981773
      39.698266,-3.981695
      39.698272,-3.98168
      39.6983,-3.981622
      39.69832,-3.981599
      39.698355,-3.981522
      39.698362,-3.981509
      39.698395,-3.981429
      39.698397,-3.981418
      39.698431,-3.981352
      39.698439,-3.981333
      39.698481,-3.981255
      39.698491,-3.981236
      39.698524,-3.98116
      39.698531,-3.981145
      39.698568,-3.981074
      39.698578,-3.981056
      39.698612,-3.980977
      39.69862,-3.980959
      39.698663,-3.980879
      39.698667,-3.980871
      39.698702,-3.98079
      39.698704,-3.980782
      39.698736,-3.980702
      39.69874,-3.980691
      39.698776,-3.980609
      39.698781,-3.980601
      39.698813,-3.980531
      39.69882,-3.980514
      39.698865,-3.980438
      39.69887,-3.980431
      39.698954,-3.980411
      39.698971,-3.980417
      39.69905,-3.980457
      39.699072,-3.980468
      39.69914,-3.980499
      39.699164,-3.980511
      39.699229,-3.980547
      39.699247,-3.980556
      39.699322,-3.980588
      39.699343,-3.980595
      39.699419,-3.980625
      39.699438,-3.980634
      39.699506,-3.980665
      39.699521,-3.980674
      39.699589,-3.980707
      39.699607,-3.980713
      39.699673,-3.980739
      39.699691,-3.980745
      39.699764,-3.980767
      39.699789,-3.980769
      39.699866,-3.980771
      39.699885,-3.980771
      39.69996,-3.98076
      39.699977,-3.980757
      39.700061,-3.980751
      39.700084,-3.980756
      39.700156,-3.980794
      39.700181,-3.980806
      39.700262,-3.980839
      39.700294,-3.980851
      39.700361,-3.980879
      39.700394,-3.980893
      39.700451,-3.980923
      39.700474,-3.980933
      39.700541,-3.980965
      39.700564,-3.980977
      39.700632,-3.981008
      39.70066,-3.98102
      39.700717,-3.981048
      39.700749,-3.981061
      39.700813,-3.98109
      39.700844,-3.981106
      39.700906,-3.981136
      39.700938,-3.981151
      39.700992,-3.981185
      39.701016,-3.981204
      39.701095,-3.981243
      39.70112,-3.98125
      39.701194,-3.981283
      39.701217,-3.981294
      39.701274,-3.981319
      39.701305,-3.981333
      39.701381,-3.98137
      39.701391,-3.981378
      39.70138,-3.981457
      39.701374,-3.98147
      39.70134,-3.981538
      39.701331,-3.981558
      39.701294,-3.981637
      39.701285,-3.981651
      39.701246,-3.981721
      39.70124,-3.981737
      39.701199,-3.981814
      39.701192,-3.981826
      39.701164,-3.981907
      39.701161,-3.981921
      39.701137,-3.982
      39.701128,-3.982024
      39.701101,-3.9821
      39.701093,-3.982123
      39.701058,-3.982204
      39.701054,-3.982219
      39.701024,-3.982282
      39.701013,-3.982304
      39.700983,-3.98237
      39.700972,-3.982391
      39.700943,-3.982458
      39.700931,-3.982482
      39.700913,-3.982541
      39.700906,-3.982585
      39.700847,-3.982648
      39.700837,-3.98266
      39.700799,-3.98274
      39.700791,-3.982762
      39.700758,-3.98282
      39.700747,-3.982855
      39.700721,-3.982932
      39.700715,-3.982954
      39.700678,-3.983032
      39.700671,-3.983047
      39.700637,-3.983127
      39.70063,-3.983141
      39.700593,-3.983213
      39.700585,-3.983222
      39.700541,-3.983298
      39.70054,-3.983309
      39.700587,-3.983363
      39.700606,-3.983371
      39.700675,-3.983406
      39.700691,-3.983416
      39.700768,-3.983449
      39.700781,-3.983448
      39.700861,-3.983471
      39.700876,-3.983478
      39.700945,-3.983521
      39.700956,-3.983529
      39.700939,-3.983617
      39.700932,-3.983627
      39.700852,-3.983618
      39.70084,-3.983612
      39.700758,-3.983585
      39.700739,-3.983573
      39.700666,-3.983545
      39.700651,-3.983536
      39.700579,-3.983497
      39.700566,-3.983491
      39.700485,-3.983528
      39.700479,-3.983535
      39.700446,-3.983607
      39.70044,-3.983619
      39.700409,-3.983691
      39.700402,-3.983709
      39.700362,-3.983776
      39.700353,-3.983791
      39.700326,-3.983866
      39.700322,-3.983882
      39.700294,-3.983961
      39.700282,-3.98398
      39.700247,-3.984049
      39.700239,-3.984069
      39.70021,-3.98415
      39.700203,-3.984178
      39.700166,-3.984237
      39.700149,-3.984256
      39.700119,-3.984325
      39.700109,-3.984341
      39.700065,-3.984406
      39.700057,-3.98443
      39.700025,-3.984507
      39.70002,-3.984519
      39.699987,-3.984593
      39.699977,-3.984612
      39.699942,-3.98469
      39.699941,-3.984705
      39.699911,-3.984782
      39.699914,-3.984795
      39.699879,-3.984871
      39.699875,-3.984883
      39.699832,-3.984959
      39.699829,-3.984961
      39.699839,-3.984883
      39.699851,-3.984863
      39.699877,-3.984793
      39.699889,-3.984776
      39.699931,-3.984704
      39.699938,-3.984687
      39.699972,-3.98461
      39.699967,-3.984594
      39.700004,-3.984521
      39.700005,-3.984501
      39.70003,-3.984431
      39.700041,-3.984412
      39.700071,-3.98434
      39.700083,-3.984321
      39.700126,-3.984266
      39.700153,-3.984259
      39.700172,-3.984191
      39.700177,-3.984168
      39.700204,-3.984111
      39.700221,-3.984087
      39.700275,-3.984015
      39.700285,-3.983992
      39.700311,-3.98391
      39.700303,-3.983902
      39.700333,-3.983824
      39.700337,-3.9838
      39.700374,-3.983732
      39.700387,-3.983717
      39.700416,-3.983642
      39.700419,-3.983627
      39.70046,-3.983555
      39.700467,-3.983544
      39.70049,-3.983465
      39.700479,-3.983453
      39.700402,-3.98342
      39.700383,-3.983411
      39.700311,-3.983369
      39.700298,-3.983362
      39.700229,-3.983326
      39.700218,-3.983312
      39.70014,-3.983327
      39.700132,-3.983341
      39.700102,-3.983424
      39.700099,-3.983437
      39.700074,-3.983516
      39.700078,-3.98353
      39.70003,-3.9836
      39.700017,-3.983618
      39.699985,-3.983685
      39.699973,-3.983698
      39.699944,-3.983763
      39.699932,-3.983795
      39.6999,-3.983878
      39.699895,-3.983894
      39.699868,-3.983973
      39.699867,-3.983986
      39.699846,-3.984051
      39.699842,-3.984078
      39.699816,-3.984133
      39.699781,-3.984157
      39.69974,-3.984231
      39.69974,-3.984249
      39.6997,-3.984321
      39.699689,-3.984338
      39.699653,-3.98441
      39.699646,-3.98443
      39.699615,-3.984503
      39.699611,-3.984516
      39.699582,-3.984586
      39.699576,-3.984599
      39.699566,-3.984688
      39.699569,-3.984691
      39.699572,-3.98461
      39.699578,-3.984598
      39.699618,-3.984518
      39.699628,-3.984505
      39.699645,-3.984428
      39.699662,-3.984412
      39.699699,-3.984335
      39.699708,-3.984319
      39.699752,-3.984243
      39.699762,-3.984218
      39.699793,-3.984148
      39.699808,-3.984108
      39.699831,-3.984041
      39.699852,-3.984003
      39.699879,-3.983928
      39.699887,-3.98389
      39.699917,-3.983825
      39.69994,-3.983779
      39.699962,-3.983737
      39.699987,-3.983693
      39.700012,-3.983619
      39.700032,-3.983591
      39.70007,-3.983514
      39.700081,-3.983481
      39.700109,-3.983398
      39.700128,-3.983387
      39.700121,-3.983301
      39.700105,-3.983293
      39.700023,-3.983257
      39.699999,-3.983246
      39.699921,-3.983218
      39.699892,-3.983189
      39.699806,-3.983165
      39.6998,-3.983169
      39.699804,-3.983236
      39.699755,-3.983279
      39.699713,-3.983345
      39.699707,-3.983362
      39.699671,-3.983439
      39.699658,-3.983459
      39.699629,-3.983527
      39.699618,-3.983556
      39.699582,-3.983628
      39.699576,-3.983645
      39.699538,-3.983719
      39.69953,-3.983737
      39.699508,-3.983811
      39.699505,-3.983824
      39.699471,-3.983891
      39.699461,-3.983906
      39.699441,-3.983954
      39.699432,-3.983997
      39.699396,-3.984077
      39.699389,-3.98409
      39.699356,-3.98416
      39.699351,-3.984176
      39.699397,-3.984101
      39.699396,-3.984097
      39.699445,-3.984024
      39.699453,-3.984
      39.69948,-3.983918
      39.699483,-3.983902
      39.699473,-3.983825
      39.699491,-3.983801
      39.699501,-3.983722
      39.699522,-3.983709
      39.699565,-3.983642
      39.699574,-3.983628
      39.699618,-3.98356
      39.699628,-3.983526
      39.699671,-3.98346
      39.699685,-3.983422
      39.699725,-3.983363
      39.699747,-3.983328
      39.699785,-3.983265
      39.699796,-3.983237
      39.699807,-3.983155
      39.699808,-3.983145
      39.699752,-3.98308
      39.699744,-3.983078
      39.699666,-3.983047
      39.699641,-3.983037
      39.699574,-3.983015
      39.699544,-3.983006
      39.699463,-3.982967
      39.699452,-3.983002
      39.699407,-3.983077
      39.699404,-3.983085
      39.699363,-3.983156
      39.699353,-3.983176
      39.699318,-3.983242
      39.69931,-3.983266
      39.699279,-3.983344
      39.699279,-3.983359
      39.699259,-3.983414
      39.699253,-3.98345
      39.699226,-3.983514
      39.699214,-3.983534
      39.699184,-3.983609
      39.699169,-3.98363
      39.699127,-3.983699
      39.699122,-3.983713
      39.699091,-3.983798
      39.699092,-3.983802
      39.699126,-3.983725
      39.699133,-3.983709
      39.699157,-3.983642
      39.699175,-3.983608
      39.699202,-3.983544
      39.699215,-3.983517
      39.69925,-3.983442
      39.699265,-3.983418
      39.69929,-3.983347
      39.699294,-3.983324
      39.699333,-3.983256
      39.699348,-3.983217
      39.699387,-3.983138
      39.699388,-3.983111
      39.699435,-3.983036
      39.699441,-3.983019
      39.699425,-3.982931
      39.699406,-3.98292
      39.699346,-3.982891
      39.699319,-3.98289
      39.699248,-3.982885
      39.699227,-3.982877
      39.699148,-3.982841
      39.69914,-3.982835
      39.69907,-3.982884
      39.699066,-3.982887
      39.699032,-3.982949
      39.699021,-3.982966
      39.698983,-3.983045
      39.698977,-3.983063
      39.698946,-3.983137
      39.698946,-3.983163
      39.698926,-3.983241
      39.69892,-3.983258
      39.698886,-3.983327
      39.698877,-3.983337
      39.698836,-3.983408
      39.698826,-3.983414
      39.698858,-3.983339
      39.698869,-3.98332
      39.698913,-3.983244
      39.698917,-3.983228
      39.698936,-3.983146
      39.698944,-3.983124
      39.698983,-3.983047
      39.698986,-3.983031
      39.699034,-3.982966
      39.699036,-3.982948
      39.699081,-3.982888
      39.699092,-3.982871
      39.699076,-3.982797
      39.699061,-3.98278
      39.698983,-3.982757
      39.69896,-3.982747
      39.698884,-3.982704
      39.698866,-3.982691
      39.698782,-3.982658
      39.698769,-3.982655
      39.698722,-3.982712
      39.698713,-3.982728
      39.698685,-3.982811
      39.698659,-3.982839
      39.698628,-3.982923
      39.698623,-3.982938
      39.698587,-3.983018
      39.698575,-3.98303
      39.698584,-3.982948
      39.698585,-3.982934
      39.698627,-3.982868
      39.698645,-3.982838
      39.69869,-3.982761
      39.6987,-3.982743
      39.698711,-3.98266
      39.698703,-3.982651
      39.698623,-3.982609
      39.698609,-3.982604
      39.698532,-3.982564
      39.698514,-3.98256
      39.698448,-3.982526
      39.698431,-3.982515
      39.698352,-3.982546
      39.698346,-3.982549
      39.698424,-3.982535
      39.698439,-3.98254
      39.698522,-3.982562
      39.698536,-3.982571
      39.698597,-3.982604
      39.698619,-3.982611
      39.698681,-3.982622
      39.69871,-3.982627
      39.698774,-3.982673
      39.698788,-3.982679
      39.698855,-3.982717
      39.698878,-3.982734
      39.698956,-3.982775
      39.699009,-3.982763
      39.699081,-3.982775
      39.699096,-3.982793
      39.699168,-3.982836
      39.699179,-3.982844
      39.69926,-3.98288
      39.699276,-3.982881
      39.699351,-3.982925
      39.699374,-3.982929
      39.699455,-3.982961
      39.699468,-3.982968
      39.699537,-3.982998
      39.699555,-3.983003
      39.699638,-3.983035
      39.699663,-3.983048
      39.69973,-3.983074
      39.699746,-3.983084
      39.699808,-3.983126
      39.699827,-3.983136
      39.6999,-3.983172
      39.699921,-3.983182
      39.699989,-3.983221
      39.700011,-3.983234
      39.700082,-3.983268
      39.700099,-3.983276
      39.700163,-3.983322
      39.700173,-3.983327
      39.700248,-3.983365
      39.700263,-3.983372
      39.700332,-3.98338
      39.700359,-3.983383
      39.700431,-3.983406
      39.700446,-3.983424
      39.700517,-3.983441
      39.700537,-3.983453
      39.700614,-3.983491
      39.700631,-3.983501
      39.700697,-3.983547
      39.700718,-3.983549
      39.700802,-3.983571
      39.700812,-3.983576
      39.70089,-3.983604
      39.700899,-3.983609
      39.700901,-3.983696
      39.700894,-3.983706
      39.700858,-3.983769
      39.700856,-3.983812
      39.700835,-3.983876
      39.700827,-3.98391
      39.700814,-3.983956
      39.700805,-3.984004
      39.700782,-3.98406
      39.700772,-3.984105
      39.700747,-3.984191
      39.700734,-3.984238
      39.700705,-3.984322
      39.700686,-3.984367
      39.700652,-3.98445
      39.700644,-3.984495
      39.700619,-3.984559
      39.700604,-3.984591
      39.700584,-3.984654
      39.700573,-3.984685
      39.700538,-3.984763
      39.70053,-3.984784
      39.700508,-3.984851
      39.700499,-3.984885
      39.700472,-3.984953
      39.700459,-3.984994
      39.700433,-3.985067
      39.700422,-3.985111
      39.700397,-3.985188
      39.700385,-3.985229
      39.700356,-3.985284
      39.700341,-3.985332
      39.700316,-3.985398
      39.700301,-3.985436
      39.700275,-3.985509
      39.70026,-3.985542
      39.700234,-3.985616
      39.700226,-3.985649
      39.700236,-3.985734
      39.70025,-3.985741
      39.700321,-3.985769
      39.700339,-3.98578
      39.700415,-3.985815
      39.70043,-3.98582
      39.700507,-3.98585
      39.700528,-3.985854
      39.700581,-3.985899
      39.700601,-3.98591
      39.700669,-3.985928
      39.700689,-3.985933
      39.70077,-3.985948
      39.700801,-3.985957
      39.700872,-3.98596
      39.700896,-3.985962
      39.700977,-3.985996
      39.700992,-3.985993
      39.701045,-3.986013
      39.701078,-3.986024
      39.701137,-3.98609
      39.701143,-3.986106
      39.701138,-3.986186
      39.701134,-3.986199
      39.701119,-3.986279
      39.701113,-3.986291
      39.701056,-3.986357
      39.70104,-3.986358
      39.70095,-3.986362
      39.70094,-3.986364
      39.700857,-3.986378
      39.700839,-3.986381
      39.700771,-3.986361
      39.70075,-3.986351
      39.700672,-3.986335
      39.700652,-3.986329
      39.700578,-3.98628
      39.700555,-3.986273
      39.70047,-3.986244
      39.70044,-3.986235
      39.700386,-3.986217
      39.700356,-3.986199
      39.700278,-3.986193
      39.700255,-3.986186
      39.700175,-3.98616
      39.700155,-3.986152
      39.700068,-3.986135
      39.700059,-3.986142
      39.700032,-3.986215
      39.700025,-3.986235
      39.699996,-3.986311
      39.699989,-3.98634
      39.69996,-3.986424
      39.699959,-3.986434
      39.700026,-3.986478
      39.700037,-3.986481
      39.700108,-3.986508
      39.700126,-3.986515
      39.700202,-3.986541
      39.700223,-3.986552
      39.700286,-3.986576
      39.700311,-3.98658
      39.700387,-3.986607
      </coordinates>
  </LineString>
</Placemark>
```